# Prove that quotient topology $\mathbb{R}/{\sim}$ is the circle topology.

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

On $\mathbb{R}$  is given relation:

$
x \sim y \Leftrightarrow (x \bmod \space 1) = (y \bmod \space 1)
$

I have to prove that quotient topology $\mathbb{R}/{\sim}$ is the circle topology. I need to build homeomorphism between $R/\sim$ and $S^1$ where $S^1 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R} , x^2 + y^2 =1 \}$., this map is $q$. And standard quorum map i v.
I need to have a function, I thought about $ f \rightarrow S^1, f(x) =(\cos 2\pi x, \sin2\pi x)$. How to show that $f$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: What did you try so far? 

You need $f$ to be: 1) continuous; 2)bijective; 3)the inverse needs to be continuous.

What are you missing?

Comment: I dont know how to show that its bijective and the inverse is also continuous.

Comment: A couple of related posts. (I won't be surprised if you can find a few more, if you search a bit.)
[Are $S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}/{\sim}$ the "same thing"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1284355), 
[Stuck on last step showing that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$, ....](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4017101), [Justify that the quotient topology ∼ is a circle topology.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4136863), 
[$\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ is homeomorphic to $S^{1}$ .](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4557409)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are $S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}/{\sim}$ the "same thing"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284355/are-s1-and-mathbbr-sim-the-same-thing)