# Quotient topology $\mathbb{R}/\sim $ where $x\sim y$ iff $x-y\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: general-topology

Let's define equivalence relation on group $\mathbb{R}$ by setting $x\sim y$ iff $x-y\in\mathbb{Z}$ by all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

What is the quotient topology?

For example if we set $x=\sqrt{2}$ and $y=\sqrt{2} + 2$, then $x-y\in\mathbb{Z}$.

So this looks similar to the case where you replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$, but $\mathbb{Z}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$. In that case the quotient topology is indiscrete.

Could someone please open up this a bit for me?

Comment: It is  homeomorphic to the circle $S_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $a \in [0,1]$. Then for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have that $a\sim a+n$. Think of this as a circle with radius $1$ rolling along the integers, identifying each of these numbers. It is a way to "wrap" the real line around a circle *a lot* of times, so that the map is surjective, but highly non-injective.

Depending on the context of your question, if you take the interval $[0,1]$ you are restricting the function to the interval, but identifying $0 \sim 1$, so that this interval with the quotient topology is indeed homeomorphic to a circle [if you're feeling technical, $S^1$].

Comment: The explicit function is given by G. Sassatelli.

Comment: This question is actually a duplicate of the following, which will prove to be a nice resource: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43956/understanding-relation-between-quotient-space-and-s1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the map $$\operatorname{cis}:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^2\\\operatorname{cis}(x)=(\cos(2\pi x),\,\sin(2\pi x))$$
and show that the induced map $\overline{\operatorname{cis}}:\Bbb R/\sim\,\to \Bbb R^2$ on the quotient space is a homeomorphism onto the image. What's the image $\operatorname{cis}(\Bbb R)$ ?